# How to setup Visual Studio to copy required DLL files into the release directory in a release build?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, release

I remember that Visual Studio did itself do the task of copying required DLL files into the release directory in a release build, but now it doesn't do it anymore, and I have to search all through the `C:\WINDOWS\system32` directory and other directories through my system to locate DLL files and paste them into the release directory of a project, searching for DLL files through the whole system can be very boring.

Do you know how to setup Visual Studio so that it copies all the required DLL files into the release directory when I build my application?

Comment: It does it for every Dll project in the same solution, when exe project is marked as startup.

Comment: I'm building exe project with 3th party dll's. so all I see in my release directory is exe file but no dlls :)

Comment: You need to document the language, it is different for C# vs C++.

Comment: Thanks, using C++ enviroinment settings.

Answer (score 0):

It should copied into your Debug Folder, but first you need to import the DLL via choose items , right click on the all windows controls , select "Choose Items" and Browse it to the corresponding type.

Comment: Can you give me a full part to "Choose items" cos I can't find that in VS2010 :/

Answer (score 0):

You can tell VB to reference the DLLs instead of moving them.  On the right-hand side in VB is the solution explorer.  Right-Click on your project and select "Add reference".  browse to the small basic DLLs (usually  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Small Basic).